# sverchok - how to "update all" via command line

Tags: sverchok

Is it possible and if yes, how can i trigger "update all" from the command line?

I need this because if i render without update all, the animation won't animate correctly (the nodes which are connected to the frame aren't updated). When i press the button, it works. But i want to render from the command line.

[image]

Comment: Enable python tool tips in user preferences, and then see what method the button calls.

Comment: Thank you!! The really bad thing is: i knew it some time ago…‍♂️sometimes I hate my memory! +1

Comment: You’re welcome :-) don’t forget you can renew your mind .